# MSBuild: How to access a property value set by a Target during the Post Build event in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have a PostBuild event which invokes a batch file and I need to pass in a particular parameter into the batch file. This parameter is populated through another task which is invoked through a Target configured to run before the PostBuildEvent.

I can see that it gets successfully displayed when displayed using the  element as part of the  section.

But $(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath) under the PostBuildEvent has an "" value. Is there a way to access this custom property in the post build event?

Example:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="GetTargetFrameworkToolsFolderName" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
   <ParameterGroup>
     <SDKFolderPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
     <TargetFrameworkVersionStr ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
     <TargetFrameworkToolsFolder ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
   </ParameterGroup>
   <Task>
     <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        TargetFrameworkToolsFolder = SDKFolderPath + "\\" + "bin\\NETFX " + TargetFrameworkVersionStr.Substring(1) + " Tools\\";
     </Code>
   </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="FindTargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath" BeforeTargets="PostBuildEvent">
   <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
     <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="SdkPath" />
   </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
   <GetTargetFrameworkToolsFolderName SDKFolderPath="$(SdkPath)" TargetFrameworkVersionStr="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)">
     <Output PropertyName="TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath" TaskParameter="TargetFrameworkToolsFolder"/>
   </GetTargetFrameworkToolsFolderName>
   <Message Text="$(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath)" Importance="normal" /> --> Displayed correctly here
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>
      call $(ProjectDir)AfterBuildCommands.bat $(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath) --> The TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath property value here seems to be empty.
   </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please put the` <PropertyGroup><PostBuildEvent>......</PropertyGroup>` into the target `FindTargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath` and change to  `AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild"`.

Comment: @Perry thanks for the reply. It worked well!!

After doing this I can no longer see the Post Build event when I look at the project properties Build Events tab in Visual Studio. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But $(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath) under the PostBuildEvent has an
>   "" value. Is there a way to access this custom property in the post
>   build event?

**In fact**, `<PostBuildEvent>` is a property and MSBuild reads all the properties first and then executes all targets.

If you put these below outside the target which defines the property `TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath`, these below will always execute first, as expected, the values of `TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath` will be empty.

To avoid it, you should put the `PostBuildEvent` and `TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath` properties in the same target and make sure the target is executed early enough, such as, run after `PrepareForBuild` target.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PostBuildEvent>
      call $(ProjectDir)AfterBuildCommands.bat $(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath) --> The TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath property value here seems to be empty.
   </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Solution**

Try this below:

```
 <UsingTask TaskName="GetTargetFrameworkToolsFolderName" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <SDKFolderPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <TargetFrameworkVersionStr ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <TargetFrameworkToolsFolder ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        TargetFrameworkToolsFolder = SDKFolderPath + "\\" + "bin\\NETFX " + TargetFrameworkVersionStr.Substring(1) + " Tools\\";
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
  <Target Name="MyFindTargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath" AfterTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
      <Output TaskParameter="Path" PropertyName="SdkPath" />
    </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
    <GetTargetFrameworkToolsFolderName SDKFolderPath="$(SdkPath)" TargetFrameworkVersionStr="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)">
      <Output PropertyName="TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath" TaskParameter="TargetFrameworkToolsFolder" />   
    </GetTargetFrameworkToolsFolderName>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <PostBuildEvent> call $(ProjectDir)AfterBuildCommands.bat $(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath) --> The TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath property value here seems to be empty.</PostBuildEvent>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="$(TargetFrameworkToolsFolderPath)" Importance="normal" />   

  </Target>
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply @Perry It worked!! 

I just have one question. After doing this I can no longer see the Post Build event when I look at the project properties Build Events tab in Visual Studio. Is there a way to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Yes marked as answer already! Is there a way to get it displayed correctly in the post build event command line in Visual Studio project properties?

Comment: l think it is impossible. When the  post build event is in the global environment, it can be showed in the project property. In this situation, you can only use the system properties. Since you want to use your custom properties which is defined locally with post build event, so it is in the local environment and cannot be showed in the project property. However, this does not affect the final result. You can modify post build event directly in the ‘xxxx.csproj’ file.